# How to use vue2-leaflet-geosearch with Vue3

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

Has anyone been able to use the [vue2-leaflet-geosearch](https://github.com/fega/vue2-leaflet-geosearch) extension with [Vue3-Leaflet](https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet)?

I have tried adding the following required parts but nothing happens on the map. There are no errors either.

```
<l-map>
  ..
  <l-geosearch :options="geosearchOptions"/>
<l-map>
```

```
import "leaflet-geosearch/dist/geosearch.css"
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from "leaflet-geosearch";
import LGeosearch from "vue2-leaflet-geosearch";
```

```
export default {
  components: {
    ..
    LGeosearch
  }
}
```

```
data() {
  return {  
    ..
    geosearchOptions: { 
      provider: new OpenStreetMapProvider(),
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [vue2-leaflet-geosearch](https://github.com/fega/vue2-leaflet-geosearch) plugin remember that the component is called **VGeosearch** instead of **LGeosearch**.

Basically change your imports in script to `VGeosearch`, and `v-geosearch` in template.